# How to use “to offer” with two objects?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I am new in this web site!

I would like to know if the following sentence is correct :

> Operating systems **offer** *processes* running in user mode *a set of
>   interfaces* that can be used to make requests for privileged
>   operations.

When *offer* has two objects (here *process* and *set of interface*), should 
one of the objects be preceded by the **to** preposition?

Comment: No, you do not need to mark an indirect object with *to* in English: it’s perfectly normal to toss Jimmy the ball.

Comment: However, though 'Operating systems offer processes running in user mode a set of interfaces that can be used to make requests for privileged operations.' is not grammatically incorrect, 'Operating systems offer, for processes running in user mode, a set of interfaces that can be used to make requests for privileged operations.' seems more reader-friendly. This is because of the extended nature of the two objects.

Comment: You might be interested in [our sister-site for English learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! I couldn't even work out what the sentence as written meant: I thought there was an "and" missing!

Comment: Hey, _I_ don't know what it means, just how to do a first-stage decode.

Comment: How about a reworking, which eliminates the passive voice: `Operating systems offer a set of interfaces that allow processes running in user mode to request privileged operations.`

Comment: @ trpt4him : Surely it's the _computer operator_ who can use the interfaces to make requests?

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth: It's common to anthropomorphise programs (processes) in computing.

Comment: @Gnubie The HAL it is. Seriously, I'd prefer a DO here (Operating systems offer the computer operator a set of interfaces ...) rather than being left to guess where anthropomorphism should be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is acceptable.

It is an instance of the rule of English grammar that for **certain** verbs, both of the following formulations are correct:

Subj Verb (IndirectObject) (DirectObject)

I give Jimmy the ball.

OR

Subj Verb (DirectObject) **to** (IndirectObject)

I give the ball to Jimmy.

In type #2, the 'to' is mandatory, as it would be if your text were modified as follows:
*Operating systems offer a set of interfaces to processes running in user mode.  These interfaces...*

**However**, sometimes formulation #2 is the only acceptable one:

I submit the report to Jane. Correct.

*I submit Jane the report.  Wrong.

In fact, I think this is probably true for *most* verbs; the tricky thing is that it's the most common verbs (offer, sing, give, pass, etc.) that allow for both variations.